# Fluid not working, stuck at midair

Tags: fluid-simulation

I've set a simple scene, big box containing everything set as domain, container inside the domain set as obstacle, icosphere at the center as inflow (shell, like the obstacle). What i got is this behaviour, the liquid floats mid air like there's some box obstacle
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed the center of the axis (sorry don't know the exact name) was not at the center of the object, also followed [here](https://blenderartists.org/t/problems-with-fluid-simulation/575886) and it worked